# Discord.py list users in a message when reaction

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

i have been trying to fix a problem for days. I want to send an embet naricht and this should be edited as soon as someone has made a reaction.

here my snipped code:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title='General Information', color=16769251)
embed.set_footer(text='General information')
embed.set_thumbnail(url=message.guild.icon_url)
embed.add_field(name='Text Header ', value=all_lines[1], inline=False)
embed.add_field(name='Text Header 2: ', value=all_lines[2], inline=False)
embed.add_field(name='Accepted Users: ', 'HERE ALL USERS WITH ✅', inline=False)
mess = await message.send(embed=embed)
await mess.add_reaction('✅')
await mess.add_reaction('❌')
```

I have already tried a lot of things but unfortunately without success I think it would be just too much to really put everything in here I still hodde that someone can help me

Here an example :
Before ( without reactions )

https://i.gyazo.com/1518bc2bfe8b55e2e790ff6481c261f7.png

After with reactions:

https://i.gyazo.com/8bf97513e1eaf567ca9dda66f54fa2f0.png

Final Version with 1 little refresh bug:

```
async def ReportRaid(self, message, bot):
    name = message.author
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    else:
        await message.delete()
    args = message.content.split(' ')
    # raid <type> <name> <setting> <min>
    #   0     1      2       3       4
    if args[0] == "/raid" or args[0] == "/Raid":
        embed = discord.Embed(title='Raid meldung von ' + str(message.author.display_name))
        embed.add_field(name='Raid Typ: ', value=args[1], inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='Name: ', value=args[2], inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name=settings.RaidSetings[args[3]], value=args[4] + " Minuten", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='Zusagen:', value='Keine Zusagen', inline=True)
        if not args[2].lower() in pkm.pokeDir[args[1].lower()]:
            await message.channel.send('Das pokemon konnte nicht gefunden werden.', delete_after=30.0)
            return
        else:
            embed.set_thumbnail(
                
                url=settings.ServerSettings["ImageURL"] + pkm.pokeDir[args[1].lower()][args[2].lower()] + '.png')
        try:
            with open('accounts/Ac' + str(name) + '.txt', "r") as fp:
                all_lines = fp.readlines()
                embed.set_footer(text='Trainer name: {} \nTrainer Code: {}'.format(all_lines[1], all_lines[3]))
                tgName = all_lines[3]
        except IOError:
            embed.set_footer(text='Keine Informationen gefunden')
            tgName = "Keinen Trainer code gefunden"
        channel = bot.get_channel(int(await guild_setings.LoadGuildSettings().get_raid_channel(message)))
        mess = await channel.send(embed=embed, delete_after=int(args[4]) * 60)
        tg.TelegramBot(message, '**\nRaid Typ: ' + args[1] + "\nName: " + args[2] + "\n" + settings.RaidSetings[args[3]] + " " + args[4] + ' Minuten\nTriainer Code: ' + tgName + '\nRaid Meldung von: ' + str(message.author.display_name)).SendToTelegramm()
        re_time = int(args[4]) * 60
        emoji_list = ['✅', '❌']
        for i in emoji_list:
            await mess.add_reaction(i)
        while True:
            users = ""
            try:
                reaction, user= await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=re_time)
                if str(reaction) == '✅':
                    mess = await channel.fetch_message(mess.id)
                    reaction_list = mess.reactions

                    for reactions in reaction_list:
                        if str(reactions) == "✅":
                            user_list = [user async for user in reactions.users() if user != bot.user]
                            for user in user_list:
                                users = users + user.mention + "\n"
                    embed_1 = discord.Embed(title='Raid meldung von ' + str(message.author.display_name))
                    embed_1.add_field(name='Raid Typ: ', value=args[1], inline=True)
                    embed_1.add_field(name='Name: ', value=args[2], inline=True)
                    embed_1.add_field(name=settings.RaidSetings[args[3]], value=args[4] + " Minuten", inline=True)
                    embed_1.add_field(name='Zusagen:', value=users, inline=True)
                    if not args[2].lower() in pkm.pokeDir[args[1].lower()]:
                        await message.channel.send('Das pokemon konnte nicht gefunden werden.', delete_after=30.0)
                        return
                    else:
                        embed_1.set_thumbnail(
                            
                            url=settings.ServerSettings["ImageURL"] + pkm.pokeDir[args[1].lower()][args[2].lower()] + '.png')
                    try:
                        with open('accounts/Ac' + str(name) + '.txt', "r") as fp:
                            all_lines = fp.readlines()
                            embed_1.set_footer(text='Trainer name: {} \nTrainer Code: {}'.format(all_lines[1], all_lines[3]))
                    except IOError:
                        embed_1.set_footer(text='Keine Informationen gefunden')
                    await mess.edit(embed = embed_1)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                break
```

Comment: How do you intend this to work? As it is right now, it is sending the embed in a DM to the person using the command. Is it supposed to send the embed in a channel and update for members as they react?

Comment: i have add 2 images eith a example before and fter reaction. I will ist all users who have reactet to my message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this. I've tried putting comments in the code along the way so you can understand better what's going on.

As the code is right now, it will not update if a user removes the reaction. If user_1 and user_2 adds reaction, and then user_1 removes reaction, they will both still show, when user_3 adds reaction, it will update to show only user_2 and user_3

You can add the code between *** in the exception as well, to update the embed one final time as the loop ends.

Another thing is that I don't know what your `all_lines` is, so I had that just as a string during testing.

```py
@client.command() # Correct this according to your code, if you're using bot or client
async def rtest(ctx):
    message = ctx.message

    # At first we create create the embed
    embed = discord.Embed(title='General Information', color=16769251)
    embed.set_footer(text='General information')
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=message.guild.icon_url)
    embed.add_field(name='Text Header ', value=all_lines[1], inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Text Header 2: ', value=all_lines[2], inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Accepted Users: ', value='HERE ALL USERS WITH ✅', inline=False)
    mess = await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    # And add our reactions to the embed
    emoji_list = ['✅', '❌']
    for i in emoji_list:
        await mess.add_reaction(i)

    # Create a while loop that will wait for users to react
    while True:
        users = "" # Create empty string that we need later
        try:
            reaction, user= await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60)

            # Check that if the reaction added is ✅, and if it is:
            if str(reaction) == "✅":
                mess = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(mess.id) #*** Need to fetch message again to get updated reaction information
                reaction_list = mess.reactions 

                # Check our reactions on the message, get user list for the ✅ reaction, ignoring the bot
                for reactions in mess.reactions:
                    if str(reactions) == "✅":
                        user_list = [user async for user in reactions.users() if user != client.user]
                        # Update the users string, to add user that reacted
                        for user in user_list:
                            users = users + user.mention + "\n"
                
                # Create an updated embed with different name, it's the same as before, but with users in last field
                embed_1 = discord.Embed(title='General Information', color=16769251)
                embed_1.set_footer(text='General information')
                embed_1.set_thumbnail(url=message.guild.icon_url)
                embed_1.add_field(name='Text Header ', value=all_lines[1], inline=False)
                embed_1.add_field(name='Text Header 2: ', value=all_lines[2], inline=False)
                embed_1.add_field(name='Accepted Users: ', value='HERE ALL USERS WITH ✅\n'+users, inline=False)

                await mess.edit(embed = embed_1) # Edit message to be the updated embed
        #***        

        # End the loop after the set amount of time (from timeout earlier)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            break
```

Comment: its look good. But i dont use or have the ctx style i work with the old one. 
i will try to add this on my cod and will give proof or you will make this for me without ctx ?

Comment: @KoriLP I'm afraid I haven't worked with the older version of discord.py. Have you tried out the solution and seen what errors show? it shouldn't be too difficult to change it over.

Comment: its work now like a charm with your version. the only proplem is the refresh, when i remove ✅

Comment: @KoriLP I know there is a way with with [asyncio.wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59433144/python-is-it-possible-to-wait-for-one-event-or-another-in-discord-py-v1-0) to check multiple events, but that does not output a timeout errror, so it keeps looping. And I'm not familiar with it and not sure how to stop. Two different ways of doing it: Dont wait_for reaction, just loop a timer and update the embed every second, or in your exception, fetch message again, update user list and embed and edit message again (wont give "live" updates, but will give one final updated embed)

Comment: i add my final version

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `bot.wait_for`, here a simple example

```
@bot.command()
async def react(ctx):
    # Sending the message
    message = await ctx.send('React with ✅')

    def check(reaction, user):
        # Checking if the user that reacted is the same as the one that invoked the command
        # also checking if the reaction is `✅` and if the reacted message is the one sent before
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction) == '✅' and reaction.message == message

    try:
        # Waiting for the reaction
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check, timeout=60.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        # If the timeout is over, deleting the message
        await message.delete()
        await ctx.send('Timeout is over')
    else:
        # If the reaction is not the one we're waiting for, send this
        await ctx.send('Bad reaction')
```

[Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

Comment: Hello, first thanks for answer me i habe add 2 images with before and after. My idea is : I will edit the message after user have reacted and add them to the list
here i have found an example but i dont work with the ctx and the example is not complete :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61849675/discord-py-bot-creating-a-list-from-reactions-of-a-specific-message

Comment: What do you mean by saying that it wont work using the context? What's wrong with it? Please add more code your question so I can help you.